# Light richtextbox control for .net (winforms)

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox, performance, replace

Is there any light version of richtextbox control? I've got to create like 300+ of them in an app which takes time, memory and slows everything down... All that I need is to have a control that will enable me changing the background/foreground of a part of the text... I'd need that in winforms... anybody know anything about some kind of replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it read-write or read-only? If it's read-only it probably wouldn't be too difficult to code this up yourself. (Plug: I have a control which I can upload somewhere if needed :)

You could use the `OnPaint` event and use different brushes and pens with Rectangles and Text.

Comment: read-only, I know that I can code it myself - but I don't have the luxury to spend the time on it... and I've got to intergrate it to actually working solution... if your solution works then hell yeah I'd give it a try :) Is there any PM option in stackoverflow? I don't want to share my email... or you could post it to megaupload.com

Comment: I'll see what I can do. I'll upload it now. It's not *brilliant* as it was for my own use - no docs, no designer support - but the designer doesnt seem to be a problem. I'll also write some docs quickly (I've got some free time ATM!)

Comment: Uploaded to Windows Live SkyDrive - http://cid-ae14082183edb6bb.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Software/TextSpanControl.zip (public folder; you don't need an account). I'll post the docs online in a few minutes.

Comment: http://cid-ae14082183edb6bb.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Software/Using%20TextSpanControl.doc (MS Word format(

Comment: Hi, this is not exactly what I need since I've got the always the same text - I just need to change the colors of fg/bg - but I'll look into your control and I'll try to adjust it to my needs. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a grid, or is it 300 fields on a single-record form?  Because if it's for a form I would suggest that there is a problem with your design.

If you need it in a grid, [consider a paging solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Pagable_DatagridView.aspx).  A paging solution would allow your users to scroll through the records, and you can still use a rich textbox, because the number of rich textboxes would be limited to the number of records displayed on the current page.

Comment: yeah, google is useless here - tried that before posting.

design is a must - it can't be designed otherwise as it's simulating something like a forum... I can't say too much about it (sorry). And the highlighting the text is also a must so that when you scroll throught that you can find the things you are searching for..

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't change the design as this is already a production app and btw. paging is in many ways bad...